# What do I make of unlinked tables in the same database?

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation

Just a basic question here but it's been bothering me for a while. Do all tables have to be related to another? I'm trying to design a database so far I have 15 tables, 13 of them have relationships with each other creating a regular snowflake pattern, but I have two other tables that only relate to each other, meaning they don't have any relationship to the any of the other 13 tables. Does this mean I should review  my design or is this considered OK?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: see my answer be interested to see if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no requirement for tables to be related to one-another.  The fact that you do have two tables separate from the other thirteen would be a code smell and you should be sure that you have not forced two different business objectives into a single database.  If the two really do support genuine use cases for the others then there's no problem.

A typical example are "staging" tables.  Here data from an external source is loaded into a stand-alone table.  Then that data is validated.  Only then is it copied across to inter-related tables.  Another is to hold system configuration or user options.  These have no foreign keys to the "business" data but support the operation of the system which uses that business data.

Lastly I would point out that the logical and physical designs can be different.  The data model (logical) may document foreign keys but the data base (physical) does not declare foreign key constraints for one reason or another.  This would be a very specific choice for particular circumstances and relatively rare, however.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the definition of "database". My answer would be a very weak *"no"*: it's not ipso facto wrong, but it can be an indicator of bad design.

- A row can be thought of as a unit of organization for columns.
- A table can be thought of as a unit of organization for rows.
- That process continues one more level. MySQL confuses the next level and that confuses lots of people.

Most say a schema can be thought of as a unit of organization for tables (in MySQL they call this a database).

That said, within the same schema I would be cautious about having tables that are unlinked to other tables. It is possible to have such a case, and it may be absolutely fine. However, *likely* what you want is to create a new schema for those lingering tables so they can grow and link with other tables themselves. So sleep easy if you understand what a *database schema* is and you need unlinked tables in the same schema. But if you don't know read up on it because it's likely those unlinked tables belong in their own schema or that you could make use of the schema functionality.

For case and point, imagine a system with that handled contacts for your company, and a separate system that handled zip codes or something of the like. You may have them both in the same schema unlinked. But, what you probably want is a separate schema `geography` and `contacts` that way you can grow those in a sane fashion and keeping them organized, and still make use of database's cross-schema functionality.

See also,

- [What's the difference between a catalog and a schema in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7022755/124486)